# How does the Fantastic Beasts film series fit into the Harry Potter Canon?

Tags: harry-potter, canon, fantastic-beasts

More or less exactly what it says on the tin: How does the released and upcoming Fantastic Beasts film series, written by JK Rowling, fit into the existing Harry Potter canon? Do they have the same level of authority as the books, the utter lack of authority of the movies, or somewhere in between?

Comment: I don't think this can be answered since JKR never really went for formal canon rules like Lucas did. So YMMV based on personal preferences.

Comment: I agree with @DVK in that everyone prioritizes canon differently, but I would personally put the upcoming *Fantastic Beasts* movie along side the other eight movies. Where that falls on one's personal spectrum of canon is going to vary person to person. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess - the question make it sound like JKR will be involved in writing the scenario (I don't know if that's true). if so, it would probably be way higher canon than 7 films

Comment: The general rule of thumb is that books + JKR interviews => Films. The films will fit into the same canon level as the other 8 films however with JKR as screenwriter, we'll have to take a judgement when the films come out.

Comment: @DVK - I don't *think* JKR is writing the screenplay, but if you have a reliable source that says she is, please correct me. She usually serves as a consultant on the films, at least she did on the first eight. She also produced at least some of the films.

Comment: @Slytherincess -  see my answer. She very strongly indicated that she is, though not specifically in those words.

Comment: @DVK - These articles at the [*Wall Street Journal*](http://blogs.wsj.com/speakeasy/2013/09/12/j-k-rowling-to-write-new-harry-potter-inspired-film-for-warner-bros/?mod=WSJ_hps_MIDDLENexttoWhatsNewsForth) and [NPR](http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2013/09/12/221724567/j-k-rowling-to-write-screenplay-for-harry-potter-spinoff) both state outright that JKR *will* be writing the screenplay. You know me -- I like definitive statements! ;)  PS - I stand corrected.

Comment: @Slytherincess - do those 2 articles have any extra JKR quotes aside those in my answer? Whether the author of the article sounds authoritative or not isn't useful - journalists aren't always right.

Comment: @DVK - If they're using the same quotes then they are just as "right" as you are. Anyway, I did cede the point -- you are right about the screenplay. I don't see the need to argue it further. :)

Comment: I read this as "How will the Fantastic Four movie fit into the Harry Potter continuity" and thought "fricking Disney"

Comment: And in the end any remaining inconsistencies will be easily explainable by some lingering after effect from *Cursed Child*, so canon compliance is no problem at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While as the answers have already made clear that the Harry Potter universe has no official canon policy, it is interesting to note that Rowling has said on twitter that these movies are canon.

> **There were obviously some major changes from the HP books to the films... Are we to take everything in these films as canonical?**
>
> **J.K. Rowling**: *Yes, because I'm writing them!*
> <sub>[Twitter](https://twitter.com/jk_rowling/status/800653857764282368)</sub>

Of course, Rowling has failed to address why the parts of the movies which aren't from her script should be canon just because she wrote other parts of it.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ach-To - A bounty? But *this* answer isn't even poking fun at The Cursed Child.

Comment: Perhaps I should accompany my bounty with a downvote :)

Answer (score 14):

There's no "official" canon in Potterverse the way LucasFilm had.

So there's no way to answer your question precisely.

Having said that, JKR will (at least according to my interpretation of her quotes) be the screenwriter for the films (unlike the original 8 Potter films) - see the bolded text for confirmation, all quotes from [BBC interview/article](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-24067557):

> "It all started when Warner Bros came to me with the suggestion of turning Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them into a film," said Rowling.
>
> "I thought it was a fun idea, **but the idea of seeing Newt Scamander, the supposed author of Fantastic Beasts, realised by another writer was difficult**.
>
> "Having lived for so long in my fictional universe, **I feel very protective of it and I already knew a lot about Newt**. As hard-core Harry Potter fans will know, I liked him so much that I even married his grandson, Rolf, to one of my favourite characters from the Harry Potter series, Luna Lovegood.
>
> She went on: "As I considered Warners' proposal, an idea took shape that I couldn't dislodge. **That is how I ended up pitching my own idea for a film to Warner Bros.**

As such,

- the realistic out of universe canonicity would definitely be **WAY more than original Potter films** (where JKR wasn't a screenwriter),
- but personally I would rate it **slightly less than the books' canonicity** because JKR as a screenwriter is under the control/influence of the director/producer of the movies.
- Of course, this could all change if JKR officially states some canon rules.

---

In addition, as far as in-universe continuity, Rowling said:

> "Although it will be set in the worldwide community of witches and wizards where I was so happy for 17 years, Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them is neither a prequel nor a sequel to the Harry Potter series, but an extension of the wizarding world.

Answer (score 4):

Now that we have established that J.K. Rowling will indeed be writing the screenplay to *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*, I wanted to answer your actual question. According to JKR, *Fantastic Beasts* will not be an extension of the *Harry Potter* universe:

> "Although it will be set in the worldwide community of witches and wizards where I was so happy for seventeen years, ***Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* is neither a prequel nor a sequel to the Harry Potter series, but an extension of the wizarding world.** The laws and customs of the hidden magical society will be familiar to anyone who has read the Harry Potter books or seen the films, but Newt's story will start in New York, seventy years before Harry's gets underway."
>   [J.K. Rowling to Write *Harry Potter* Spinoff](http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2013/09/12/221724567/j-k-rowling-to-write-screenplay-for-harry-potter-spinoff) -- NPR -- 9.12.13

So, *Fantastic Beasts* will *not* fit into existing *Harry Potter* canon.

Since we haven't seen the movie yet, it's impossible to assess its authenticity in comparison to the *Harry Potter* movies, but I would suggest that perhaps *Fantastic Beasts* might have a higher level of authenticity within the wizarding world's canon (which stands alone from Harry and his story) because it's a stand alone set within the wizarding world. This is just an idea, though, on my part.

As a movie, compared to the *Harry Potter* movies, in the same way as I mentioned above, I think *Fantastic Beasts* would have greater authority. One, the author herself is writing the screenplay, and she is very protective of her universe; she's also very exacting. Two, while the *Fantastic Beasts* and *Harry Potter* movies come from the same universe, their stories do not intersect. While the book *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* is a bestiary, it also has a brief one page bio of Newt Scamander and an introduction that has a good bit of canon information on Magizoology. Whether JKR will use this in her screenplay, I don't know, but should she use her existing canon, and build Newt's story on that canon foundation, it would put *Fantastic Beasts* closer to JKR's personal wizarding canon *as a movie*.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your answer.  Reading JKR's commentary, it seems clear that even though Harry, etc. will not be in the films, they will be in the same universe. I don't understand what you mean by a distinction between wizarding world canon and Harry Potter canon (e.g. Beedle the Bard doesn't involve Harry Potter characters, but is canon as a book of legends)

Comment: I consider the Harry Potter universe to be identical to the Wizarding World universe, even if Harry's stories are just a small part of the larger universe.  I have never heard of their being two different canons/universes; I am perfectly willing to accept that there are alternate universes or less canonical works, but not that something not involving Harry Potter, but in the same world is not part of the same universe (especially given how the term universe is understood in fandom).

Comment: Yes, they are set in the same universe: the wizarding world. As Newt's story begins 70 years before Harry's story it is highly unlikely Harry and co. would be making cameos. JKR has said *Fantastic Beasts* will be "an extension of the wizarding world", which I read as being set in the wizarding world, but a story totally separate from Harry's.

Comment: Thing is, this isn't fandom. Yes, "universe" means many different things in fandom. But I am quoting to you what the author of the series has said; her word will always take precedence over fandom particulars. If you prefer the word "universe", you could substitute "universe" where I have written "world". And you are free to hate my answer :) But it is important to remember that Stack Exchange is infinitely different than fandom. Here, people look for hard facts and sensible subjectivity. In fandom, anything goes!

Comment: 1/2 @Slytherincess I definitely don't hate your answer! I actually think the last two paragraphs make up a good answer (which  is why I didn't downvote).  I also love SE's emphasis on definite answers (there's a reason for quality being so high here).  Your JKR quote is also very useful.  When I say fandom, I only mean that most fans and critics of SF works would see universe as being part of a connected group of works, even if characters and settings don't crossover (EG Heinlein's future history).  The only part of the answer I was confused by was your differentiation between

Comment: 2/2 Harry Potter Universe and Wizarding World Universe, and I think that this is because we mean different things by universe.

Comment: @eliyahu-g -- Actually, I think we do mean the same thing, but for whatever reason aren't connecting. I do want to clarify that HP is most often classified as fantasy, as opposed to sci-fi (which I will totally admit I don't really read; I do prefer fantasy as a genre). I understand what you're saying about Heinlein. It's exactly what I was trying to say; it seems I didn't express myself adequately. Well, at least we know who's writing the screenplay. :)

Comment: glad we agree. FYI, by SF, I mean speculative fiction, not scifi

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fantastic_Beasts_and_Where_to_Find_Them_%28film_trilogy%29) the films will be indeed written by JKR but I doubt they can be written according to the book strictly, as the book is not a story, but rather an documentary or journal of the magical creatures in the Harry Potter world. The movies can indeed be just about the trip of the author but it is likely more action will be needed to make a good movie.

Comment: For the record, the book is a "[bestiary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bestiary)" rather than a journal.

Comment: Thank you Richard. Indeed that is the best and the closest would be encyclopaedia I guess, I meant journal because the author was describing his experiences and the movie is likely to base its action around this idea (as the rest is just raw information).

Comment: Technically isn't the book supposed to be a textbook that Harry owned? From what I've quickly gathered about it, it contains the history of Magizoology and has 75 different species.  I suppose you could call it a bestiary in the sense that it talks about different magical creatures.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 -- You are correct in that *Fantastic Beasts* was a textbook Harry was required to purchase his first year. It's on his welcome letter in the chapter *Diagon Alley* in *Philosopher's Stone*. :)

Comment: What is the HP Wikia's source? Is it reliable? Curious. :)

Comment: If you mean about JKR as a screen writer, the article is referencing this Independent article: http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/films/news/jk-rowling-to-write-new-harry-potterinspired-film-series-based-on-fantastic-beasts-and-where-to-find-them-8812270.html

Comment: I would say the wikias are from time to time reliable sources because almost everything in cited.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - I can only speak to the HP Wikia, but, yes, it is sometimes correct. Citations are important, but just because something is cited doesn't mean the source is reliable (Think *Weekly World News*: "I was a teenage tarantula!".). That's why I ask. :)

Comment: On the IMDB JK Rowling is said to be the writer as well.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3183660/

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - First, let me acknowledge that JKR **is** writing the screenplay for *Fantastic Beasts*. I've been convinced. That said -- and I'm truly not trying to be difficult; feel free to ignore this comment -- the IMDB is an iffy source for me because it can be edited by its users. I'm better at book canon than movie canon and trivia, so what may appear to be resistance on my part is almost always, rather, me trying to get as much info as possible and suss it all out. Hope this makes sense. :)

Comment: @Slytherincess From what I gathered IMDB isn't actually an iffy source if you read their entry where they get their information it shows that they constantly go through consistency checks.  They also use a variety of different sources as stated in this quote from http://www.imdb.com/help/show_leaf?infosource "Our sources of information include, but are not limited to, on-screen credits, press kits, official bios, autobiographies, and interviews."  So just because something can be edited by users shouldn't be counted out since they check the information before posting it to their site.