# Did Luna and Neville ever date at all after the "Harry Potter" series ended?

Tags: harry-potter

We know at the end of the initial *Harry Potter* movie series that Neville Longbottom had a bit of a crush on Luna Lovegood, and during the Battle of Hogwarts, sought her out to "confess" to her. As an adult, we know Neville married Hannah Abbott and [Luna married Rolf Scamander, Newt Scamander's grandson](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/79299/98028)... but the years between are in question.

How did Luna take Neville's confession?

Did the two perhaps date at all, similar to Harry and Cho Chang, or did she plainly not return his feelings?

Comment: Is this in the books?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, or Rowling's ramblings.

Comment: Oh, never mind... him having a crush on her is apparently part of the movies, which still had Rowling overseeing them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a Rowling quote to the effect of "the two of them wouldn't get together, Luna's weirdness is not what Neville is looking for in a partner."

Comment: There is a hint at this in the seventh horcrux fanfic. Since a lot of the things in that fic are accurate or very close to what actually happened in the final book, i wouldnt be surprised if there actually has been some obscure mention about this by rowling

Comment: If the op says this was in the movie then may be it was an officialky sanctioned idea by jk rowling at some point

Answer (score 8):

## Most likely not, they were incompatible.

In a section on her old website, JKR addressed the possibility of Luna and Neville “hooking up” in a later book. Considering that Harry Potter is a relatively clean series, “hook up” in this case most likely refers to the possibility of them dating rather than a physical encounter. JKR considered herself to be quashing the rumor with her response, stating Luna and Neville were too different to ever be able to feel much more for each other than friendship.

> **Luna and Neville will hook up in HP&THBP**
>
> The Luna/Neville shippers are much less vehement and scary than the Harry/Hermione, Ron/Hermione tribes, so I hope I won’t receive too much hate mail for quashing this rumour. I see Neville and Luna as very different kinds of people and while they share a certain isolation within Hogwarts, I don’t think that’s enough to foster true love - friendship, perhaps, although I think that Neville would always find Luna’s wilder flights of fancy alarming. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Rumors (JKR’s old website)](https://www.therowlinglibrary.com/jkrowling.com/textonly/en/rumours_view_id=24.html)*</sup></sub>

This statement was from before all the books were published, and certainly before the Deathly Hallows movie in which Neville wished to confess a crush, so it is possible that JKR could have changed her mind on their relationship. However, in the books it is never even hinted at that either Neville or Luna had any sort of crush on the other. Therefore from the information given in the books, there is no reason to believe they would have dated. Additionally, JKR never mentions Luna and Neville dating in any later interviews. Considering it is never mentioned anywhere but the movies, which often had some inconsistencies with the books, there is no real evidence to imply that Luna and Neville were meant to have dated in book canon.